# Chemfig PBAT structure

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

I'm writing my master thesis and I'm in trouble with PBAT structure using `chemfig`.
I can't draw its structure as in the picture:
[image: PBAT structure]

Could you help me please? Thanks in advance

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's recommended to post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276104/134144)  shows how you can draw a (different) copolymer using `chemfig`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you! I wrote the question quickly so I didn't add a MWE. I will do it surely next time!

Comment: @leandriis I will take a look at it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\chemfig[angle increment=30,atom style={scale=0.7}]{
    H-[@{a1,0.5}1,1.5]O-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]O-[1](=[3]O)-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1](=[9]O)-[@{z1,0.4}1,2]O(-[@{a2,0.8}:210,,,,draw=none])-[-1]-[1]-[-1]-[1]-[-1]O-[1](=[3]O)-[-1]*6([0]=-=(-[1](=[3]O)-[@{z2,0.6}-1,1.5]OH)-=-)
}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 33pt, depth = 28pt, indice = m]{a1}{z1}
\polymerdelim[delimiters ={[]}, height = 33pt, depth = 28pt, indice = n]{a2}{z2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!